# What steps to take for my scenario using WCF

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I am a total beginner in WCF.
I should start a project where several clients are included. There is a wcf web service controler that after a call from an specific client about a certain question it will retrive data from a server in London and then it will pass it back to the corresponding client in a different country e.g.

Clients and service are far away. the only way of transportation is through HTTP and intenet connection. Service should be able to callback also so i guess it will be dualHttpBinding.

since I am a complete newbie, What step do I need to take to achieve this? What concepts in WCF and what type of binding configuration is required?

Any advice on where and how to start would be appreciated by me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "service should be able to callback"? What you have described is still only request-response scenario without any callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the scenario, you have a client X who will make a request of the server, which will cause the server to send a message to client Y somewhere else? Is that correct? If the server just has to respond to client X, then you can use a normal binding and it's pretty easy to get going (basicHttpBinding is very straightforward to use and for something like this would work well).

If you do need callbacks, you have to be careful with dualHttpBinding. Due to the way HTTP works, dualHttpBinding requires an address where the server can initiate a message to the client. If you have clients behind firewalls or home routers, this will NOT work without port forwarding being configured. For that type of operation, net.tcp is a much better binding as it will let you do callbacks without the firewall issue (as the server can send back along the connection the client opened).

At any rate, as for where to start, I suggest you get simple communication working first. There are several good WCF starter guides out there. Use one of those to create a simple service and get a client talking to it. Then start adding some methods. Don't attempt the callbacks until you're familiar and comfortable with client-server requests.

Comment: "If I understand the scenario, you have a client X who will make a request of the server, which will cause the server to send a message to client Y somewhere else? Is that correct?" Yes it is! and by the way I checked for samples in MSDN in VB. Are they useful for my case? Thank you

Comment: The ones for how to get started are, yeah. Not sure the stuff on dualHttpBinding is, but because of how poorly that works in the real world I tend to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on WCF below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731190(VS.100).aspx

WCF is a beast. There's a lot of information involved and it will take you time to get your head wrapped around it. Look around MSDN for a ton of information (and how-to documents) about different WCF scenarios.